# composite-unique-key-validation - laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

seems it's not possible with built-in validators, how I should implement this feature in the model?

```
 $rules = [

            'user_id' => 'required|unique:service_details,user_id',
            'service_id'=>'required|unique:service_details,service_id'
         ];
```

above will prevent duplicacy of `user_id` and `service_id`  independently which is not my requirement

it will reject

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
```

because 1  is duplicate but it should be accepted as i want composite unique key

Comment: if you don't want to write a custom validation, then run the query (which will fail), catch the exception, check the error, and if it is indeed failed due to unique key constraint, then add the error message in the message bag and redirect to the previous page.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Composite unique field validation [is provided out-of-the-box in 5.0+](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique). I can't speak for earlier versions.

You can essentially specify a where clause for when your unique validation rule applies. E.g.

```
'term'  => 'unique:terms,term,NULL,id,taxonomy,category'
```

This rule says that `term` should be unique on the `terms` table but only where the `taxonomy` is equal to "category".

For example, it will prevent a "news" category being duplicated but I can still have a "news" tag.

---

I don't know your schema but in your case it'd be something like this:

```
$user_id = Request::get('user_id', $default);
$service_id = Request::get('service_id', $default);  
// or another way of specifying the accompanying service/user ID for the where clauses

$rules = [
    'user_id' => 'unique:service_details,user_id,NULL,id,service_id,' . $service_id;
    'service_id' => 'unique:service_details,service_id,NULL,id,user_id,' . $user_id;
];
```

Comment: Thank you @harryg, the link you provided was really helpful. Through that I was able to solve my problem too. :)

Answer (score 10):

My solution

Laravel 5.3 and 5.4

Note: Without model binding

**Store**

```
'required',
Rule::unique('service_details','service_id')->where(function ($query) {
      $query->where('user_id', $this->request->get('user_id'));
})
```

**Update**

```
'required',
Rule::unique('service_details','service_id')->ignore($this->route()->id)->where(function ($query) {
      $query->where('user_id', $this->request->get('user_id'));
})
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible out of the box in Laravel. You would either have to write a [custom validator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules) or use a package for that.

Here is one that should do what you need:
- https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

With this package, your rules could look like the following:

```
$rules = array(
    'user_id' => 'required|unique_with:service_details,service_id',
    'service_id' => 'required',
);
```

It works for both Laravel 4 and 5.

Comment: yeah, would suggest that solution today too. At the time of writing this option was not available (laravel 4 days)

Answer (score 3):

With the help of this [link](https://brianretterer.com/quick-tip-laravel-unique-validation/) , I am able to achieve composite validation from out of the box laravel 5.3. I knew it is old question and answered already. In my case vendor and client combination is unique.

My sample code is below

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'Vendor'=> 'bail|required|int',
        'Client'=> 'bail|required|int',      
        'discount'=> 'required|numeric',            
        'Client'=>'unique:billings,client_id,vendor_id'.$request->Vendor
    ]);
```

Comment: Good Answer. Nice and Precise, Thanks.