# Composite unique key validation in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel-5.1

I need to validate unique combination of key. I am doing this for follow user functionality.

Here is my tables:

`users table:`

`id` `name` `email`

`follows table:`

`id` `user_id (user id who is following)` `author_id (user id who is followed)`

Now should be a condition that same `user_id` and `author_id` can not be repeat, because a user can not follow another user twice.

I have used the following code from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093061/composite-unique-key-validation-laravel):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'author_id' => 'required|unique_with:users,id',
        'user_id' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

but it gives me error:

```
Method [validateUniqueWith] does not exist.
```

Can some one suggest me for this in laravel 5.1

**Edit:**

I have gone through the already given answer, but I think that is for laravel4, and it did not work for me in laravel5

[composite-unique-key-validation - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093061/composite-unique-key-validation-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composite-unique-key-validation - laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093061/composite-unique-key-validation-laravel)

Comment: I have tried the same but it is giving me error

Comment: Method [validateUniqueWith] does not exist.

Comment: have you installed the dependencies. follow the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093061/composite-unique-key-validation-laravel and https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator