# Laravel validation with condition on a specific column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-validation

I want to make a field unique but only with a condition.  The field `start_date` in my event table should be unique only if the `pitch_id` is the same.

To clarify: a reservation start date can be the same date if the pitch is not the same.  I mean if the start date and the pitch id are unique it should not pass.

Here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
    $this->validate($request, [
        'start_date' => ['unique:reservations']
    ]);

    $events = new Reservation();
    $events->type = $request->get('type');
    $events->start_date = $request->get('start_date');
    $events->end_date = $request->get('end_date');
    $events->pitch_id = $request->input('pitch_id');
    $events->save();
    return redirect('Reservations')->with('success', 'réservation crée avec succès');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [composite-unique-key-validation - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093061/composite-unique-key-validation-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [ 'start_date' => ['unique:reservations,start_date,NULL,NULL,pitch_id,'.$request->input('pitch_id')]
    ]); 
    $events = Reservation::create($request->all());
    return redirect('Reservations')->with('success', 'réservation crée avec succès');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique