# validation in Laravel for unique for column

Tags: sql, laravel, validation

Eg: I am having table called Sports. In that sports table there columns are

1. Sports Name,
2. player name
3. material required ..

Fields are

| sports | name | player name | material requires |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cricket | cook | bat ball stumps |
| 2 | football | Messi | football boot |
| 3 | cricket | MSD | bat ball stumps |

In this table I want to make unique column for material required eg: MSD can have only one bat. if he add bat once again it want to show already added .for same  Messi already football if he add once again means it want to  display error already add?

Validate:

```
sports name => 'required',
player name => 'required',
material requires => ?
```

Comment: Don't place more than one material in your column. Not the best database design

Comment: The answer here should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093061/composite-unique-key-validation-laravel

Comment: Is `material required` a json field or are you using pivot ?

Answer (score 0):

use the validator, it will make it easy for you as an example like below:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request -> all(), ['material' => 'required|unique:modelname', 'player name' => 'required', 'sports name' -=>'required']);
```

Comment: required|unique:modelname         this will make unique for whole table(sports).just this column (material requires )should be unique for each id of( player name)only .for eg: player name: ronaldo , material required : boot ,jersey . next player name: Messi  material required :boat,ball,jersey .   when ronald like to add football he can add because he didn't have football in (material requires ) column. when Messi add football it want show error because he already had it in (material requires) column

Comment: Yeah, that is what it would do. it will make that only column unique not the whole table. I have used it and it's working. because material is one column not the whole table.  if you want to that thing you should check it with a query to make sure if it has a material. if the query return not null, then you can send a response that you already have a material added for that specific person.

Comment: but its not working bro .when i stored same value for eg (bat) its shows already taken when i am using for another id .in laravel 5 [they useds this methods 'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id]/email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'